# .Htaccess URL Rewriting - Clean URLs not working using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Hi I want to rewrite below URL `https://example.com/item?id=223` to `https://example.com/google/223`. Here ID will be dynamically generated

I have tried this but it is not working

```
RewriteRule ^google/$ item?id=$1    [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please confirm if you are hitting link `https://example.com/item?id=223` in your browser?

Comment: example.com is just for understanding. The actual URL is something else. Is it needed to share the actual url?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I meant is: does your url have: `item?id=223` in it?

Comment: Yes, what I want is if someone writes https://example.com/item?id=223 url should be rewritten to https://example.com/google/223 with same content as https://example.com/item?id=223

Comment: ok so you want to change url in browser to `google/223` and in backend does it get served by index.php file OR some other file?

Comment: Yes, exactly it will work like that. In backend it served be served using index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure that your htaccess rules file and your index.php files are present in same folder.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect in browser to new URL.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/item\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /google/%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to index.php in backend server.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^google/(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. what if it is served by item.php

Comment: @Pardeep, then replace `index.php` in above code with `item.php` and let me know how it goes?

Comment: I changed index.php to item.php it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pardeep, what sample url you are hitting? what error are you getting? Are item.php and htaccess present in same location?

Comment: I hit https://example.com/google/223 

it gives 404 error and item.php is in same folder and it should receive the value of id and execute the query

Comment: @Pardeep, as per your question it looked you are hitting `https://example.com/item?id=223`? Isn't it the case.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.